# Fix restore invalid column reference editor by clicking Ok?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

This `SSIS` job essentially exports data from an oracle `PLSQL` database to a `SQL Server` database.

Whenever I change something in the `WHERE` clause of the query that will be used for the bulk insert, I get the following screen. I just click 'Ok' and everything's fixed.

Two questions: why do I get this error every time I change the query? I'm not changing the columns or the size. The output is not affected since I'm not touching the columns.

Is it a *valid* fix just to click 'Ok'? Whenever I see the red X after changing the output query, I literally just double-click on the `SQL Server Destination` and click 'Ok'.

This is the query. I simply change the WHERE clause; for example, `trunc(sysdate)-2` to `trunc(sysdate)-1`

```
SELECT
datetime
,EmplCode
,TotalSales
,TotalRev
TotalTax
FROM Employee
WHERE     
Employee.EmplCode like 'STX%'
and trunc(Employee.DATETIME) = trunc(sysdate)-2 --This is what I change
```

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename the columns in the where clause? Are there functions in the where clause? Please show the code in the where clause.

If you right click on the task, and choose advanced, you can view/edit the input and  output columns. You can see then see the effect of clicking on the 'OK' button. SSIS is either renaming or changing the data type of one or more columns. Its probably ok but you should be aware of what SSIS is doing. Trust but verify to quote a former president....

Comment: I've added the query. I only change the `WHERE` clause, specifically `trunc(sysdate)-2`

Comment: I don't know Oracle types as well as I should. Is Datetime a default column available for every row?

Comment: The actual column type for column `Employee.DATETIME` is type `DATE`.

Comment: Again SQL Server is probably adjusting (mangling) the types. You can see what it is doing by following the process I suggested.